# joining urls with urljoin in python

Tags: python, urllib, urlparse

I am trying to do some web scraping but I have some problems in joining relative and root urls

for example the root url is: `http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v2`

and the relative url is: `../v2/meila07a/meila07a.pdf`

As I use urljoin in urlparse: the result is odd:

`http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/v2/meila07a/meila07a.pdf`

Which is not a valid link. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Two dots (`..`) means go back once in the hierarchy, change the second link to `./v2/meila07a/meila07a.pdf` and it should be working fine.

Or you can also change the root one to `http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v2/`, thanks to this change it will no longer dispose of `v2` at the end because the root was not set to a proper directory.